# Why jquery trim decimal out

Tags: javascript, jquery

my jquery for  to show the total price cuts out any `.00` or `.` anything how can I get it to show price

Comment: Please always add code to your questions so we can see what you have tested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`parseInt()` returns **int**egers, that means no decimals, you can use `parseFloat()` instead to preserve decimals and then `toFixed(2)` to round to only two

```
var qty = parseInt($('#Qty').val());  //added cast to int
var price = parseFloat($('#pricetag').text().replace(/^\D/, ''), 10) * qty;
price = '\u00A3' + price.toFixed(2);
$('#sprice').text(price);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use JavaScript's [`toFixed`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp) function:

```
var num = 10;
var result = num.toFixed(2);
console.log(result);    //will display 10.00
```

So in your example:

```
var price = parseFloat($('#pricetag').text().replace(/^\D/, ''), 10) * qty;
price = '\u00A3' + price.toFixed(2);
```